# Creating docker image from lxc container tar file

Tags: linux, docker, lxc

i am trying to create a docker image from an lxc_container tar file,
i am able to import it using the docker import command

```
sudo docker import ./app.tar
```

i was able to import it and run it,

```
docker run -i 1442710c3bae /bin/csh
```

but the problem i am facing is, when opening a shell there is no prompt
but the basic linux commands seems to be working.
another thing is some the /dev/ devices in the tar file is not there in docker container

the lxc container tar is SLES11 os with a set of applications. 
i am trying to import it into a SLES15 machine running docker version

i am completely new to docker, can anyone help to understand what is going wrong?